# Why subtracting interval from time with time zone in postgresql for GMT+1 adds 1 hour to result

Tags: postgresql

I have this query which returns `2024-03-18 17:29:00.000000 +00:00`

```sql
SELECT (
   ('MAR 18 2024 16:30 GMT+1'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) -
   ('1 minute'::INTERVAL)
);
```

I would have thought the return value would be in UTC time, and therefore would be `2024-03-18 15:29:00.000000 +00:00`. This because within the same time zone GMT +1, minus one minute would be 16:29. 16:29 GMT +1 is 15:29 UTC.

Why is it one hour forward instead?

Comment: I think you have a typo in your question. You say the query returns X but you were expecting X

Comment: The query returns 17:29:00 but I am expected 15:29:00. Have added more detail to question if that clarifies...

Comment: `('MAR 18 2024 16:30 GMT+1'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` -> UTC 16:30 converted to GMT+1 = 17:30.

Comment: Isn't `('MAR 18 2024 16:30 GMT+1'::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)` -> UTC 15:30?

Comment: Take a look  at [POSIX Time Zone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html). You are being bit by ; *... the positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.)*